# Find the almost certain convergence of $(Y_n), \, n \geq 1$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Hi I'm having trouble understanding this problem

> Consider a succession of tosses of a balanced die. Let $X_k$ be the result of the $k$-th face and $Y_n = \max(X_k), k ≤ n.$
> Find the almost certain convergence of $(Y_n)_{n \geq 1}$.

I'm just don't know how should I find the convergence of this random variable.

Can someone explain/help me a method to find the convergence?

Thank you!

Comment: By $Y_n=\max(X_k),k\leq n$, do you mean that $Y_n$ is the maximum in the sequence of $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$? In that case, you are looking at almost surely convergence to 6, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't see the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convergence you don't even require any result from probability theory. $(Y_n)$ is an increasing sequence of real numbers bounded by $6$ (at each sample point) so it converges at every sample point $\omega$.
To show that the limiting random variable $Z$ has to be $6$ w.p. $1$ consider $P(Z <6)=P(X_k <6 \forall k)=\prod_k P(X_k <6)=\prod_k P(X_1 <6)=0$ since $P(X_1 <6)=\frac  5 6 <1$.

Comment: Oh! thanks now I understand how to prove this kind of probelms. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, could you explian why is the product please?

Comment: @Massimo2015MX $P(Z<6Z)\leq \prod_{k=1}^{n} P(X_1<6)=p^{n}$ for any positive integer $n$ where $p=P(X_1<6)$. Since $p<1$ it follows that $p^{n}\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Ok! I got a little confused, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the probability of $Y_n=6$:

$$\begin{align*}
\Pr\{Y_n=6\} & = \Pr\{\text{at least one $X_k = 6$, for $0\leq k\leq n$}\} \\
 & = 1 - \Pr\{\text{no $X_k = 6$, for $0\leq k\leq n$}\} \\
 & = 1-\left(1-\frac{1}{6}\right)^n \rightarrow 1, \quad \text{ as } n\rightarrow\infty
\end{align*}
$$
which proves the convergence in probability. To prove almost surely convergence you need to prove that the probability of the set of all sequences $\{X^n: X^n=\{X_k\}_{k=1}^n, \nexists X_k=6\}$ tends to zero. The proof, aside from some details, follows the same idea as in the convergence in probability.

Comment: Oh thanks, I get the idea! Thank you very much